# NestJs @Request type in controller using an Authguard attaches unknown key

Tags: typescript, nestjs

When I use the `AuthGuard('jwt')` everything works fine I believe.. but within the AuthGuard it appears to attach a key that is not associated to the `Request` type in the `Express` package

**user.controller.ts**

```js
import { /* ... */, Req } from '@nestjs/common'
import { Request } from 'express'

@Controller('user')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
export class UserController {
  @Version('1')
  @Post('create')
  async createUsers(@Body() dto: UserDto, @Req() req: Request): Promise<any> {
    console.log(req.user) // <-- Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'
  }
}
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    })
  }

  async validate(data: any): Promise<any> {
    const foo = data
    return foo
  }
}
```

Whatever I return from the async method `validate` is attached as `user` key within the `@Req()` method in the controller. is there a separate type that I should be using for the argument of `@Req() req: Reques` ? because I don't wish to do `@Req() req: any`

Comment: you must create another interface that enhances the `Request` interface from `express`. Something like `type SessionRequest = Request & { user: unknown }`

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom decorator typed, something like:

```
   //user.decorator.ts 
   import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
    export const User = createParamDecorator(
      (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
        const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        return request.user;
      },
    );
```

then you can simply use it in your controller like this:

```
        @Get('hi')
      example(@Req() request: Request,@User() user: UserEntity) { //UserEntity ,interface or whatever you want 
        const userId = user.id; 
      }
```

for more information please visit the official doc [custom-decorators](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators)

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look and let you know if it was the solution to my issue, and if so give you the checkmark

Comment: This worked really well for me. You don't need `@Req() request: Request,` in the above example since the other parameter handles the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that best suited me for this was @MicaelLevi comment.